# R - How to scrape value from a table cell using xpath?

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I'm working in R trying to scrape some stats for multiple players from `www.baseball-reference.com`. I've been able to scrape other elements from specific pages on the site, but have run into problems scraping from a particular table that appears on all the players' stats pages. The table id is 'batting_value' and the node caption that appears on the page as the table header is 'Player Value--Batting'.

Here's an example page:

```
https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/b/brownro02.shtml
```

I'm interested in scraping the 'PA' value from the bottom row of the 'Player Value--Batting' table.

I've tried `inspect > copy xpath`, which gets me the `xpath` in the case of the above example url.

```
//*[@id="batting_value"]/tfoot/tr/td[3]
```

But when I try to scrape using that path...

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(rvest)

 xpath <- '//*[@id="batting_value"]/tfoot/tr/td[3]'

 tables <- read_html(url)

 pa <- tables %>%
         html_node(xpath = xpath) %>%
         html_text()
 pa
[1] NA
```

It looks like the API isn't even finding the node:

```
 tables %>%
         html_node(xpath = xpath)
{xml_missing}
<NA>
```

Why isn't this node being found by `html_node`, and how would I go about scraping this value from the Player Value--Batting table?

Comment: Please edit your code and remove all the `>` so it's easier for others to copy and paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's inside the comment, right ?

```
url ='https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/b/brownro02.shtml'
library(rvest)
tab = read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="all_batting_value"]//comment()') %>%
  html_text() %>% read_html() %>% 
  html_table() %>% as.data.frame()

tab
       Year       Age        Tm Lg   G  PA Rbat Rbaser Rdp Rfield Rpos RAA  WAA Rrep RAR  WAR waaWL. X162WL. oWAR dWAR oRAR   Salary   Pos
1      1999        23       CHC NL  33  70   -4      0   0     -3    0  -8 -0.8    2  -5 -0.5  0.478   0.495 -0.3 -0.3   -3           7/89
2      2000        24       CHC NL  45  98    4      0   0      0   -1   3  0.3    3   6  0.6  0.507   0.502  0.6 -0.2    7 $210,000  7/98
3      2001        25       CHC NL  39  92    2      0   0      0   -1   0  0.0    3   3  0.3  0.500   0.500  0.3 -0.2    3 $230,000 7/D98
4      2002        26       CHC NL 111 231  -11     -1   0     -3   -2 -16 -1.7    7  -9 -1.0  0.485   0.490 -0.7 -0.6   -6 $255,000 78/9D
5 4 Seasons 4 Seasons 4 Seasons    228 491   -9     -1   0     -6   -4 -21 -2.2   15  -5 -0.8  0.491   0.495 -0.1 -1.2    1 $695,000      
  Awards
1     NA
2     NA
3     NA
4     NA
5     NA
```